# How to draw children on top of other (non-parent) widgets in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to draw the children of a kivy widget on top of their parents "siblings". By sibling I mean a widget of the same class as their parent's class but a different instance.
Kivy draws these by default in the same order as their respective parents: first parent, all its children, then second parent, all its children etc. Thus, sometimes a child is on top of it's "uncle", and sometimes it is below, depending on which was drawn first, their parent or their "uncle".

I understand the basics of the kivy widget tree (or at least I hope I do), but cannot figure out how to influence the draw order of the children. I guess there must be something I'm missing.
As a side note: I want to create (and delete) the child widgets at runtime.

```
       from kivy.app import App
       from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
       from kivy.uix.button import Button

   class ParentButton(Button):
       def __init__(self, pos, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(**kwargs)
           self.size_hint = None, None
           self.pos = pos
      def on_release(self):
          self.add_widget(ChildButton())

  class ChildButton(Button):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(**kwargs)
          self.size_hint = None, None
          self.pos = (0, 0)
      def on_release(self):
          if self.parent.pos[0] &lt; 150:
              self.pos = (150, 50)
          else:
              self.pos = (150, 150)

  class Layout(FloatLayout):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(**kwargs)
          self.add_widget(ParentButton((100, 100)))
          self.add_widget(ParentButton((200, 100)))

  class TestApp(App):
      def build(self):
          return Layout()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      TestApp().run()
```

In my code example, I have two buttons, each creating a child button. When pressing the child button, it moves so that it overlaps with its own parent and with the other button, which is not it's parent but of the same class. A button created by the left button will be drawn on top of the left button, but below the right button. A button created by the right button will be drawn on top of both. This is actually expected behaviour, but I want to change it so that all children will be above (or below) all of their parent class. Can someone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to manually manipulate the canvas.children list in order to influence drawing order, without needing to change the order of the widget children at all. You probably need to be careful only to reorder it though, not to remove anything outside of the normal remove_widget calls.

In general this rarely comes up because it's usually simplest to just reorder the widgets as children of the parent.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly: Do you suggest to make the ChildButton as child of the proper parent instead of manipulating the drawing order? This actually solves the problem, as I never need to overlap on both parent and uncle, but it's not very intuitive in my context. In the meanwhile I learned about tree traversal on wikipedia (unfortunately I don't have a computer since background), and I think I can rephrase the question: kivy uses pre-order tree traversal for drawing, is it possible to make it breadth first?